# Spring Boot how to query data without returning it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Apologies for asking such a newbie question!

I know from Spring Boot's docs, that I can do this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

But how can I query the same information, then perform some sort of logical transformation on it, before returning it to the client?

Using the findByLastName, the results from the DB are returned directly.

Comment: *...perform some sort of logical transformation* A  more specific example of what you might want to do might yield more answers.

Comment: Spring Data Rest gives you projections and excerpts to modify the returned data to some extent, but as Alan says, you need to give an example of a specific use case.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts

Comment: What I mean by some sort of logical transformation, would be to take the results, and say group them into categories, or apply a custom sort function, or a custom filter, does that help.  I mean basicaly take the result set from the DB, and do something to the result set before returning it to the client.  It could be as simple as formatting date values for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had similar problem and as far as i understand the issue, there is no convenient solution for me and you to do that . 
you will have to implement your own controller and there to address all your logic. 
look at @RepositoryRestController and implement your own methoods with your own logic. 
the solution i came ac

```
@RestController
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/event/")
public class EventController {

    @Autowired
    EventService eventService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upcoming", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    List<EventProjection> checkIfUserParticipatesUpcoming(@RequestParam(value = "userId") String userId) {
            return eventService.checkIfUserParticipatesUpcoming(userId);
     }
}
```

with full implementation of the business logic in the event service as you usually do in spring .

`Spring-Data-Rest` in awesome for basic stuff but its not as stretchy as you would like it to be.

if there is a better answer i will be glad to hear it also.

*a little note , I'm a sinner. the return type supposed to be `HttpEntity` with compatible return type of the server 200/201/204 but I'm just in development stages and not yet in production. *

Comment: This sort of answers my question, in fact, it led to me to find the answer I was looking for. It's possibly to define a requestMapping in a controller which invokes a service method, which calls one of the methods in the repository.  See this example: http://javabeat.net/spring-data-jpa/

Comment: this is exactly what i ment when i said "with full implementation of the business logic in the event service as you usually do in spring ". as you can see in my code example i refer to the service where the real buiness logic belongs

Answer (score 0):

After asking this question, I subsequently found the following documentation, which outlines exactly how to achieve this:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers

```
public class ScannerController {

    private final ScannerRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public ScannerController(ScannerRepository repo) { 
        repository = repo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/scanners/search/listProducers") 
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getProducers() {
        List<String> producers = repository.listProducers(); 

        //
        // do some intermediate processing, logging, etc. with the producers
        //

        Resources<String> resources = new Resources<String>(producers); 

        resources.add(linkTo(methodOn(ScannerController.class).getProducers()).withSelfRel()); 

        // add other links as needed

        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources); 
    }

}
```

Note: you will also have to import the following packages to make this work:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;
```